# Error while running clustimage module assoicated with _t_sne.py file

Tags: embedding, tsne

An error occurrs while running this module, clustimage. The error refers to the 'embedding' setting when "embedding='tsne'". If I run the code while "embedding='none'", it works fine. The concern is that embedding is very practical for visual purposes and should be used. Any ideas why this error occurs and how to resolve it?

clustimage resource link:
https://erdogant.github.io/clustimage/pages/html/Abstract.html

**clustimage module**

```
cl = Clustimage(method='pca',
                embedding='tsne',
                grayscale=False,
                dim=(128,128),
                params_pca={'n_components':0.95},
                store_to_disk=True,
                verbose=50)
```

**_t_sne.py code**

```
update = momentum * update - learning_rate * grad
        p += update
```

**error**

```
File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/_t_sne.py", line 372, in _gradient_descent
    update = momentum * update - learning_rate * grad

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')
```

Comment: clustimage embedding link: https://erdogant.github.io/clustimage/pages/html/clustimage.clustimage.html?highlight=embedding#clustimage.clustimage.Clustimage.embedding

Answer (score 0):

The author of clustimage found the answer:

> Thank you for reporting! I found the issue: learning_rate='auto' seems the problem. I simply removed the parameter.

Resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).